# how to use flume to get the data from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

Now, i have to use the flume to get the data from the kafka. what i want to achieve is to consume the data from kafka every 30 minute and write the data into the file, which i can use to do the online learning. The config is as follows:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 5000
a1.sources.r1.batchDurationMillis = 2000
a1.sources.r1.kafka.zookeeperConnect = host
a1.sources.r1.kafka.topics = topic

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = file


# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1

a1.sinks.k1.type  = file_roll
a1.sinks.k1.sink.directory = /home/flume_log
a1.sinks.k1.sink.rollInterval=30
a1.sinks.k1.channel  =  c1
```

if the config has something wrong. when i run the test.conf, although i have produce some data, i can't get it in the file. All the files are empty

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use Flume? You can write to file from Kafka, using Kafka Connect.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt  is there any  methods that can write the data from the kafka into the file every 30min? i once wrote a code for writing the data into the file if i a piece of record was produced, that is to say, real-time monitoring. If the data produced in a period was enormous, i guess it will be a big waste of the efficiency. Can you give me more suggestion?